# How do I cast between different data types

Tags: c#

Ok, before i ask for some help with the issue I'm having at hand, I've googled and I've read through many links on other sites like this one. I'm trying to figure out variables using my Hungarian notation. So please don't flag or dislike my post I'm really needing some experts help here.

I've done a few already but i honestly don't know if I've done it right. But I'm really trying to attempt them i just don't have anyone else to turn to for help other than here call me a noob but I've been trying to figure these out for about 3 days now.

Sites I've used in trying to figure it out are -

1. [Hungarian Notation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260976(v=vs.60).aspx)
2. [Casting and Type Conversions (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)
3. -I would post more but the system wont let me post any more links.

> ```
>  intNum1 =30
>  dblNum2=45.3
>  strNum3=”88”
>  text box named txtNum4
>  intNum5 = 0
> ```

Correct the following statements with the correct casting.

```
txtNum4.Text = intNum1;
strNum3 = txtNum4.Text;
dblNum2 = intNum1;
intNum1 = dblNum2;
txtNum4.Text = dblNum2 * 2;
intNum1 = txtNum4.Text;
dblNum2 = txtNum4.Text;
txtNum4.Text = dblNum2 * 2;
txtNum4.Text = “The value is “ + dblNum2;
Modify the previous casting to display dblNum2 as currency.
```

Here's what I've done so far if I'm doing them wrong say so because i have no clue i usually learn with visual aids but i have nothing.

```
int intNum1 = 30;
txtNum4.Text = intNum1.ToString();

string strNum3 = "88";
strNum3 = txtNum4.Text;

Double dblNum2 = 45.3;
dblNum2 = (double)intNum1;

int intnum1;
double dblnum2 = 45.3;
intnum1 = (int)dblnum2;

txtNum4.Text = (dblNum2 * 2).ToString();
```

**Doc that i got the Info from**

Assume you have following variables using my Hungarian notation as a datatype hint:

```
1. intNum1 =30 
2. dblNum2=45.3
3. strNum3=”88”
4. Assume you have a text box named txtNum4 
5. intNum5 = 0
```

Although the text and
strings hold numbers, they are not values but rather characters. Correct the following statements by adding the correct casting.  If no casting is needed indicate so:

```
1.  txtNum4.Text = intNum1;
2.  strNum3 = txtNum4.Text;
3.  dblNum2 = intNum1;
4.  intNum1 = dblNum2;
5.  txtNum4.Text = dblNum2 * 2;
6.  intNum1 = txtNum4.Text;
7.  dblNum2 = txtNum4.Text;
8.  txtNum4.Text = dblNum2 * 2;
9.  txtNum4.Text = “The value is “ + dblNum2;
10. Modify the previous problem to display dblNum2 as currency.
```

Comment: Maybe i'm a still a bit asleep but...i really don't understand what is your question, or what problem do you have...And what does Hungarian notation have with it

Comment: @Pikoh it seems some people have got this as a homework. There have been questions about the same task in the last days...

Comment: Sorry mate I'm half asleep as well, But I'm trying correct the following statements with the correct casting to them is all.

Comment: As I understand it, the notation is only there to tell you what dataType it is and you are expected to insert the proper casts into the assignments, right?

Comment: the good idea would be to just compile it and see what fails

Comment: The point of closing questions isn´t because we don´t like you or soimething, it is because your question might seem unclear or has any other problems making it impossible to answer following the guidelines for StackOverflow. So asking for not closing is quite pointless. Anyway: what do you mean by "I´m doing them whring"? What exactly is whrong?

Comment: @Pikoh you are write its an online class and there is no instructor to help  to be honest they post these word docs and say search to figure it out. ive tried my hardest to figure it out and im lost at this point i have no clue ive never even heard of Hungarian notation

Comment: Forget about Hugarian notation. It's just telling you the type of the variable adding it to the start of its name

Comment: I'll reedit and post exactly to what the doc says and its not much..

Comment: Anyway, this is not very difficult. Just create a new project, add the variables and the statements, and visual studio would tell you what is wrong. You just have to play with casting and `<type>.Parse` methods.

Comment: Thanks  Pikoh ill play around with it a little more and see if i can figure it out.

Comment: @wkl your right. Its the insert to the proper cast.

Comment: Just check what conversions are implicit and put the conversions that are not implicit. Check this link for the numeric implicit and explicit conversions https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y5b434w4.aspx

Comment: I got almost all of it done i cant figure out how to do the last two problems 9 and 10 can someone help me with those 2?

Answer (score 1):

You are not converting between datatypes. You are unboxing them instead of converting hence the failure. Check this link and the last code sample, which has the same error you have.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yz2be5wk.aspx

You should have used the conversion and/or the parsing avariable functions.

```
double dblTwelve = Convert.ToDouble(12); 
int intTwelve = Int32.Parse("12");
```

Edit: If you are not certain that the content of the parsed value fits the desired datatype, you can always use the TryParse function instead the Parse, or use a try-catch to control the possible exception.

```
double doubleInput;
string input = "not-a-number";
bool isDouble = double.TryParse(input, out doubleInput);
```